# How to draw Tables

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to draw this Table: [image]

I tried:

```
\documentclass[book,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array}  

\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|l|}
        \hline
       \multicolumn{1}{p{10cm}}{\centering Sommaire d'identification}\\ \hline
        Titre &  Importer projet \\ \hline 
        But &  Dessiner automate à partir d’un fichier MDL ou XML \\ \hline
        Résumé & L’utilisateur se charge de l’importation du fichier MDL ou XML \\ \hline
        Acteur &  Utilisateur \\ \hline
       \multicolumn{1}{p{10cm}}{ Description des enchainements}\\ \hline
       Pré conditions & Post conditions\\ \hline
       Fichier MDL ou fichier XML & automate \\ \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{p{10cm}}{ Scénario nominal}\\ \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{p{10cm}}{ %
     \begin{enumerate}
    \item  L’utilisateur accède au menu bar <<Fichier>>.
    \item  L’utilisateur choisit l’option <<Importer projet>>.
    \item  Le système affiche une interface de la fenêtre de sélection.
    \item  L’utilisateur choisit le fichier qu’il veut importer.
    \item  Le système affiche un automate.
     \end{enumerate}
     }\\ \hline
     \multicolumn{1}{p{10cm}}{Enchaînement alternatif}\\ \hline
     \multicolumn{1}{p{10cm}}{
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[E1:] 1. L’extension du fichier est différente de XML et MDL.\\
    2.  Le système affiche un message d’erreur.
    \item[E2 :] 1. La structure du fichier est incorrecte.\\
           2. Le système affiche un message d’erreur.
    \end{itemize}
    }\\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You really ought not want to draw a table which looks like that unless for some purely instrumental reason such as fulfilment of a pact with the devil or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this layout, based on `tabularx` and `booktabs`. For the enumerate environments, I use `enumitem` for its versatility:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gillius2, fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, booktabs, caption}%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\captionsetup{font=rm}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\tablename}{\scshape Tableau}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sffamily\setlength\belowrulesep{1.5ex}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}XX}
    \toprule
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\large Sommaire d'identification}\\
   \addlinespace
   \midrule
   \addlinespace
    Titre & Importer projet \\ \addlinespace
    But & Dessiner automate à partir d’un fichier MDL ou XML \\ %
    \addlinespace
    Résumé & L’utilisateur se charge de l’importation du fichier MDL ou XML \\
    \addlinespace
    Acteur & Utilisateur \\
   \addlinespace
    \midrule
   \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}l}{Description des enchaînements}\\
   \addlinespace
   Pré conditions & \bfseries Post conditions\\
   \addlinespace
   \mdseries Fichier MDL ou fichier XML & automate \\
   \midrule
   \addlinespace
  \multicolumn{2}{ p{\textwidth}}{ %
  \textbf{Scénario nominal }
 \begin{enumerate}[wide]
\item L’utilisateur accède au menu bar « Fichier ».
\item L’utilisateur choisit l’option « Importer projet ».
\item Le système affiche une interface de la fenêtre de sélection.
\item L’utilisateur choisit le fichier qu’il veut importer.
\item Le système affiche un automate.
 \end{enumerate}
 }\\
 \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{%
\textbf{Enchaînement alternatif}
\begin{enumerate}[wide, label =E\,\arabic*:,leftmargin=*, itemsep = 2ex]
\item%
 \begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*.]
 \item L’extension du fichier est différente de XML et MDL.
 \item Le système affiche un message d’erreur.
\end{enumerate}
\item
 \begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*.]
 \item La structure du fichier est incorrecte.%
\item Le système affiche un message d’erreur.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
}\\%
 \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Déroulement du scénario « Importer un projet ».} \label{import}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]